# Can I initialize string after declaration?

Tags: c

Can I initialize string after declaration?

```
char *s;
s = "test";
```

instead of

```
char *s = "test";
```

Comment: You need to allocate the memory required by the string in the first case.  It's done automatically for you in the second.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: nope, in both cases `s` points to a read-only string allocated statically.

Comment: better you should try this...

Comment: What is the difference between two?

Comment: The first one is assignment and the second one is initialization. Right or wrong?

Comment: @user1301568: you have to do an assignment in order to initialize something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, but keep in mind that with that statements you are storing in `s` a pointer to a read-only string allocated elsewhere. Any attempt to modify it will result in undefined behavior (i.e., on some compilers it may work, but often will just crash). That's why usually you use a `const char *` for that thing.

Comment: is "test" string literal on stack?

Comment: What is the difference between two?

Comment: @Nandkumar: no, it's allocated like a global.

Comment: @user1301568: there's no substantial difference.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int 
main(void)
{
    // `s' is a pointer to `const char' because `s' may point to a string which
    // is in read-only memory.
    char const *s;
    s = "hello";
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
```

NB: It doesn't work with arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int 
main(void)
{
    char s[32];
    s = "hello"; // Syntax error.
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is correct for pointers (as mentioned above) because the string inside quotes is allocated from the compiler at compile time, so you can point to this memory address. The problems comes when you try change its contents or when you have a fixed size array that want to point there